# Twig add content after template is generated

Tags: php, mysql, templates, twig

i got a twig template which is dynamically generating 31 accordion items with a reference to the current date. (One  Loop does the job)
Means for today 2014-02-10 there will be 14 items starting with 2014-02-10 then 2014-02-09, 2014-02-8 ... back to 2014-02-27.

I am going to add content into those accordion items.

Of course the content belongs to specific dates.

I am asking myself whats the best practice to add the conent since the template is one loop which creates all the 31 items ?

Working with `<IF>` within the loop of the template ?
Add Content after template is generated with a simple CMS or somth. ? If Yes howto do so ?

Different strategy ?

The content changes a lot. Content is added and deleted to the items daily.

Thank you

Zomh

//EDIT

**.tmpl Code**

```
    <section class="ac-container">

    {% for key,value in resultArr %}
    <div>
        <input id="ac-{{key}}" name="accordion-1" type="radio" {% if loop.first %}checked{% endif %}  />
        <label for="ac-{{key}}">{{value}}</label>
            <article class="ac-large">
                    <figure>Some content... </figure>
            </article>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

</section>
```

**resultArr:**

```
array(15) {
```

[10]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-10"
  [9]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-09"
  [8]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-08"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-07"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-06"
  [5]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-05"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-04"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-03"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2014-02-02"
  [1](http://www7.pic-upload.de/11.02.14/uvs99mxnymos.jpg)=>
  string(10) "2014-02-01"
  [31]=>
  string(10) "2014-01-31"
  [30]=>
  string(10) "2014-01-30"
  [29]=>
  string(10) "2014-01-29"
  [28]=>
  string(10) "2014-01-28"
  [27]=>
  string(10) "2014-01-27"
}

**Output**

[Picture of the Output](http://www7.pic-upload.de/11.02.14/uvs99mxnymos.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, but I have difficulty with understanding your question... Could you your current code?

Comment: Did some editing hope its clear now

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to prepare your `resultArr` to structure like that:

```
$resultArr = array(
    array(
        'acKey' => '10',
        'date' => '2014-02-10',
        'content' => 'Your content for 2014-02-10 date'
    ),
    array(
        'acKey' => '09',
        'date' => '2014-02-09',
        'content' => 'Your content for 2014-02-09 date'
    ),
    // and so on
)
```

After that, you have to change your twig template to:

```
<section class="ac-container">

    {% for element in resultArr %}
    <div>
        <input id="ac-{{ element.acKey }}" name="accordion-1" type="radio" {% if loop.first %}checked{% endif %}  />
        <label for="ac-{{ element.acKey }}">{{ element.date }}</label>
            <article class="ac-large">
                    <figure>{{ element.content }}</figure>
            </article>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

</section>
```